Istanbul Turkey Visa
I got single entry visa for turkey from 16/02/2024 to 13/08/2024 I went Istanbul on 16/02/2024 for 7 nights the visa is expiring on 13/08/2024 and its single entry visa can i go again on the same visa for 4 night between these dates 23/07/2024 to 27/07/2024.

Is the term single entry vague or unclear in some way?

If you are a UK citizen as the tag "uk-citizens" implies, you do not need visa for short stays in Turkey afaik.

You have a single entry visa, and you already used it. You cannot use it again. You need a new visa.

No, you cannot visit again using the visa that you have already used. You need to reapply for the visa. If you intend to visit the country again, I will suggest you to apply for a multiple entry visa that often costs more.
